# AWS Kinesis Analytics SQL to transform rows to a list

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, cloud, postgresql-9.1, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I have a Destination `Stream` that looks as follows for example :

```
Company_ID      Product      User_Tag    Count
   123            P1             T1        15
   123            P1             T2        10
   123            P1             T3        10
```

I want the Final Output as follows :

```
Company_ID      Product       User_Tag    Count
   123            P1         [T1,T2,T3]    35
```

I tried using `listagg` on `User_Tag` but I get an error saying `no function signature found` . Is this even possible on AWS Kinesis SQL on streaming data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL - Array Aggregate

```
SELECT company_id,
       product,
       Array_agg(user_tag),
       Sum(count)
FROM   stream
GROUP  BY company_id,
          product; 

 company_id | product | array_agg  | sum
------------+---------+------------+-----
        123 | P1      | {T1,T2,T3} |  35
```

SQL - String aggregate:

```
SELECT company_id,
       product,
       String_agg(user_tag, ','),
       Sum(count)
FROM   stream
GROUP  BY company_id,
          product; 
    

   company_id | product | string_agg | sum
------------+---------+------------+-----
        123 | P1      | T1,T2,T3   |  35
```

**Edit** [Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=e5ac2351ceea949edb68649044648354) to demo.

Comment: I get the following error : No match found for function signature STRING_AGG(<CHARACTER>, <CHARACTER>)

Comment: same for array_agg , do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: Are you running this on Postgresql?
I have added link to the demo , vide Edit.

Comment: running this on aws kinesis analytics

Comment: Checked the available aggregate functions for Kinesis Analytics here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/sqlref/sql-reference-functions.html , no AGG function is available , we will need to find some other way. Let me try.

Comment: thank you for your help , struggling with it past few hours . any help highly appreciated .